# Display Results from %Mariaex{} Map

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I had to use the Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!/4 to query my database.
It worked great and returns the results I was expecting.

When I try to display the results on a Phoenix page using `<%= for result <- @results do %>` I get this error

```
protocol Enumerable not implemented for %Mariaex.Result{...}
```

So the question is, how do I enumerate over the results to display them in an HTML table?

---

Dogbert got me onto the right track but I ultimately ended up doing this so that I can have individual control of each table cell (e.g. assign classes, attributes, etc.).

```
<%= for row <- @results.rows do %>
<% [field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5, _, _, _] = row  %>
<tr>
  <td nowrap><%= field_1 %></td>
  <td class="fancy><%= field_2 %></td>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [README](https://github.com/xerions/mariaex#usage), the fields' data is stored in the `rows` field of the struct and the name of the columns are in `columns`. To convert these into a key/value pair you can use `Enum.zip`. This should work:

```
<%= for row <- @results.rows do %>
  <%= for {column, value} <- Enum.zip(@results.columns, row) do %>
    <%= inspect {column, value} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

PS: I'd rename the variable to `@result`.

Comment: Thanks - I was almost there with it having discovered that the data was in the rows list, but I missed the columns list. 
Your answer was a huge help!!